# Erro na instalação do pycryptodomex no osmc raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Quando tento instalar o "pycryptodomex" ou "pycryptodome" me dá esse erro aqui no final, já verifiquei o header file "stdint.h" e ele está na pasta descrita no erro:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DLTC_NO_ASM -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/src/MD2.o

In file included from src/pycrypto_common.h:46:0,

   from src/MD2.c:28:

/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/include/stdint.h:9:26: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory

 # include_next <stdint.h>

compilation terminated.

error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-6MWbw6/pycryptodomex/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-xJOrOC-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-6MWbw6/pycryptodomex
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta faltando instalar o python-dev, tente isso:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -t jessie python-dev
```